# Negative peak detector, capacitor

Tags: diodes

[image: diode motherfucking circuit]

So I don't get it, why is the capacitor oriented with its + terminal on the bottom?

Wouldn't this peak detector work just as fine if + terminal is on the top?

Like, when diode is on, \$V_o\$ would be negative, and capacitor would charge to \$-V_{b}\$ + \$Vd_{on}\$, wouldn't it?

I mean the way you calculate voltage across the capacitor is how... like when diode is on, voltage from plus terminal minus voltage at the negative terminal

voltage at + terminal is \$-V_b\$ and on plus side it's \$(-Vb + Vdon)\$ ???

so \$-Vb - (-Vb + Vdon) \$

?????

So confused.

Comment: Because that bottom plate is going to be the more positive one, considering the diode's direction. And polarized capacitors don't like when you apply a more negative voltage to the positive terminal!

Comment: If Vo=-ve on the negative terminal, with +ve = 0V,  you have it correctly polarized.  E-caps can handle about 10% of rated voltage in reverse, no more.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Well, don't you calculate voltage across a capacitor the same way you calculate it across a resistor? So when $V_s$ = $-V_b$, so what voltage is seen at the + terminal of capacitor? Wouldn't the voltage across a capacitor be like: "voltage at +side minus voltage at -side". At negative terminal of capacitor you'd have -Vb + Vd_${on}$, what would you have on the positive terminal? I'm guessing I'm struggling with these basic ideas...

Comment: Get a copy of Millman and Taub's book "Pulse & Digital Circuits" to explore this world of diodes. Used book, cheap.

Comment: No @Jack  +ve cap is 0V and negative detected voltage goes to -ve lead on cap. Thus the cap see a positive voltage in correct polarity.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 So I'm guessing the short answer to my previous question is "no"? Voltage across capacitor is calculated different than across a resistor. So does it mean that if negative voltage is applied to capacitor it's better to have the positive terminal of capacitor facing that negative voltage? So you said earlier that "E-caps can handle about 10% of rated voltage in reverse", would a capacitor break if you keep applying positive voltage to the capacitor in this case? (by simply making the diode forward biased, since it's reverse biased in the picture).

Comment: Whether a voltage between two points is 'positive' or 'negative' depends on which terminal you designate as the reference point. Your schematic shows Vo being positive on the diode terminal and negative on the ground terminal. In reality the ground terminal will be positive (relative to the diode terminal) and the diode terminal will be negative (relative to ground).

Comment: @BruceAbbott what would change if capacitor had + terminal on the top?

Comment: The '+' sign indicates a polarized capacitor. If it was an Aluminium or Tantalum electrolytic type then it would be damaged by reverse polarity.

Comment: @BruceAbbott so is it correct to assume, that in this case when voltage source is $-V_b$ and diode conducts, capacitor will charge up according to this logic: you have negative voltage + voltage rise across diode, so capacitor will charge up to negative voltage of the source + voltage rise of diode???? And does it mean that current across $R_s$ assumed to be 0 because capacitor will act like an open circuit?

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to visualize if you turn the schematic upside down, so that components with more negative voltage are lower down:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAG1Zn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now the reason for the capacitor's orientation is obvious, and you can see that it will charge 'up' (down?) to a *negative* voltage (relative to Ground).

When V1 initially goes negative the diode will conduct because the Cathode is more negative than the Anode. This will cause the capacitor to charge through R1 and D1 until the diode stops conducting at about 0.5V, at which point the capacitor will have about 0.5V less voltage on it than the supply.

Note that with the voltmeter connected as shown it will read *positive* voltage because its positive terminal is connected to Ground.

Comment: "at which point the capacitor will have about 0.5V less voltage on it than the supply." Why? because if you do KVL for C1, you go like: "oh, voltage drop in V1 then voltage rise in D1, that means C1 will charge up to V1 - D1??" Also, what's the voltage across R1 if Vs is 4V? Is it safe to assume 4V- 0.5V? Diode won't be conducting, so it'll be like an open circuit, wouldn't it?

Comment: If the capacitor is initially discharged then all the supply voltage is put across R1 and D1. As the capacitor charges up it takes more voltage away from the resistor and diode, so current reduces. Voltage across the resistor decreases proportional to the reduced current, but the diode drops relatively constant voltage until the current is almost zero. At this point the resistor is dropping close to zero volts and the diode is 'turned off' (as you say 'like an open circuit') with some voltage across it - typically ~0.5V for a silicon diode.